# Is both CHR(10) and CHR(13) needed in windows?

Tags: windows, forms, vbscript, plsql, cmd

I have to fix a problem in an application. The application is an Oracle Form deployed to an application server. The form at the end of is process which is to press a button is suppose to send an email. At the end of the code in the button it has an PL/SQL code that calls a CMD file inside C:\ When the PL/SQL code calls the CMD file it passed 3 arguments which are string variables. I have a problem with the third.

this is a sample of the 3rd argument:

```sql
'** VACATION REQUEST **'||chr(10)||
'**********************'||chr(10)||chr(10)||
'** Notice: Forward this mail to example@example.com'||chr(10)||
'           stating whether the request is approved or rejected'||chr(10)||chr(10)||
'Request Number   : '||:peticiones_vacaciones.codigo||chr(10)||
'Date of Request  : '||to_char(:peticiones_vacaciones.fecha_peticion,'dd/mm/yyyy')
  ||chr(10)||chr(10)
```

The cmd file calls a Vbscript which creates an Outlook object and passes the third variable as an HTML body.

The problem to all this is that when someone receives this email in the body of the email will only see the first line which is ** VACATION REQUEST **  all the other part of the body is missing.

I found that in windows with vbscript you have to put both CHR(10) and CHR(13) at the end of a line ???

Is that true ? Can this be the problem in my case ?

Answer (score 4):

The email standard ([RCF2822](//www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822)) says that lines must be separated by carriage return and line feed (aka `CRLF`, or `chr(13)+chr(10)`) no matter the source or destination platform (ie. this isn't a windows issue).

Typically `CRLF` is most important when separating headers, but it further limits the length of a single line of text to no more than 998 characters, and preferably no more than 78 characters (1000,80 without the `CRLF` characters).

In [RFC2822 Section 2.3](//www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.3) it further states that the body must only contain `CRLF` *together*, they must not appear independently so it's quite likely that some piece of the mail infrastructure is truncating at that first `chr(10)`.  If you wanted to include such characters in the body alone you'd need to use a different form of content encoding... `base64` for example (but that's out of scope of what you're asking for)

All that said... if your above code is VBScript you should be using `&` to [concatenate](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-7.0) two strings together (not `||`).  If it's [plsql](//www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/plsql.html) script have you confirmed that the output of that statement is a large amount of text and not just the first string?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try it! The || is used in PL/SQL because the string is build inside the form and then passes as an argument in the cmd file that calls the vbscript the code above is PL/SQL code that generates a string.

Comment: i found a solution at my own at the end this code was an HTML code so i replaced all the chr (10) & (13) with <br> so i can shape my text using html tags since html was the result after all

Answer (score 2):

The email standards specify that lines should end with CR/LF (chr(13)/chr(10)). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1

In general Windows text files follow the same format.